# How to avoid blinking in Form.Invalidate()?

Tags: c#, invalidation

I'm using `f.Invalidate()` to repaint graphics in my C# program but the graphic blinks as it refreshes. I'm also using `e.Graphics.DrawImage()` inside the `f_Paint()` method.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set the property `DoubleBuffered` to true.

Since it's a protected property, you'll need to make your own control:

```
class Canvas : Control {
    public Canvas() { DoubleBuffered = true; }
}
```

Comment: how can i do that? is it a method under Form?

Comment: It's a property of `Control`.

Comment: Easiest way is to do `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` in the load event of your form.

Comment: Im not familiar with Control. lol. I typed Control. but there's no DoubleBuffered. i also tried this.DoubleBuffering but this. has no DoubleBuffering either. then i tried f.DoubleBuffered but it says that its inaccessible due to protection level. what's wrong? o.O

Comment: You need to make your own class that inherits `Control` and sets `DoubleBuffered` to true.  Change `f` to an instance of that class.

Comment: try setting it in the form's constructor instead of the load event, or setting it in the property grid from the designer.  I forgot that it's a protected member.

Comment: like class Bufferer{ }? What do I need to type to inherit the control. I know ':' means inheritance so would it be ':Control' ?

Comment: Exactly.  I would call the control `Canvas`.

Comment: can you guide me step by step? I have 2 class already. one is the Program.cs which creates the other one which is Game.cs. My Game class constructor triggers all. So then? I need to create another .cs?

Comment: @SLaks I assumed he was using a form with a designer where it automatically created a new class that inherits from Form.  since it's inherited it would have access to the protected members.  If he just whipped up a new form and hooked up the events programatically then no, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: The designer will never show protected properties.  Also, he's using a control on his form.

Comment: To make things clearer i have this Program.cs. In it, I call the Game g = new Game(), meaning, im creating a new Game class. In the Game.cs, i have a constructor public Game() which initializes all things, like form dimensions, registering eventHandlers, etc. So what do I need to do next?

Comment: Sorry guys, I see my problem.  I assumed based on his variable names that he was painting directly to the form (not a control).

Comment: aright so i created another .cs and i named it Canvas.cs. What should I put inside? should I also put ': Control' after the class Canvas?

Comment: yeah. im using the .Invalidate() method of a form. Form f = new Form(); then i use f.Invalidate() each time i want to repaint.

Comment: yep, I made a bad assumption.  I thought you were working from code inside a designer generated Form, not from methods hooked up to an instance of a Form.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I really want to use that .DoubleBuffered method. :(

Comment: @ReinanContawi: Yes.  Then, change `f` to a `Canvas`.

Comment: All these comments could be used to make the answer better so we're not drowning in comments

Comment: I really don't know where to put the ':Control' thing. @SLaks, can you give me a snippet starting from class Canvas{? And can you indicate the header files I need to use?

Comment: You're right; I forgot the base type.  .Net doesn't use header files.

Comment: @SLaks i did it correctly but it still blinks. what do i do next?

Comment: You need to draw on the canvas, not on other controls.  Defining this class will not magically affect your existing controls.

Comment: So I will do 'Canvas cv = new Canvas()' in my Game.cs and then put e.Graphics.DrawImage(...) inside the Canvas() and whenever I paint, I do the 'new Canvas()'?

Comment: No; you need to change the control that you're drawing on to be a Canvas.   _Creating a new Canvas will not magically affect your existing controls._

Comment: Canvas.Invalidate() instead of f.Invalidate()?

Comment: Do I need to create another method in the Canvas.cs?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of OOP and WinForms development.

Comment: I mean what do I do next after setting the DoubleBuffered?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do all of your drawing to an in memory bitmap first, then paint that bitmap to the form so that it is all drawn on screen at once.

```
Image buffer = new Bitmap(width, height, colorDepth); //I usually use 32BppARGB as my color depth
Graphics gr = Graphics.fromImage(buffer);

//Do all your drawing with "gr"

gr.Dispose();
e.graphics.drawImage(buffer,0,0);
buffer.Dispose();
```

You can be more efficient by keeping `buffer` around longer and not recreating it every frame. but DON'T keep `gr` around, it should be created and disposed each time you paint.

Comment: I declared Bitmap avatar = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile("filename.png"));
then e.Graphics.DrawImage(avatar, 1, 1, 100, 100)

Comment: Right, just replace my "draw your stuff here" comment with all your same drawing code, but use `gr` instead of `e.graphics`.  This will  effectively buffer all your drawing calls and make them paint to the screen at once, removing the flicker. Setting `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` as SLaks said will also probably help.

Comment: You may need to also override the Background Paint method and DO NOT CALL base.OnPaintBackground - it's not required and by not doing so, you don't "clear" the previous contents.

Comment: is the colorDepth important? How do i set the colorDepth?

Comment: its not working. it says that 'A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property..'

Comment: The color depth determines how many colors are available to draw with. 32bppARGB will generally give you the most options.  If you know you won't need transparency you can do 32bppRGB instead.  The higher the bit depth the more memory the image will take up.

Comment: in the Graphics gr = Graphics.fromImage(buffer);

Comment: Do you have all this code inside the Paint event?  That error makes it sound like you are initializing some of it at the class level outside of a method.

Comment: It's not in the Paint event. Its outside the methods. Just like a global variable.

Comment: try moving it all inside the paint event.

Comment: i set it like this: Image buffer = new Bitmap(200,200,32) and it says the 3rd parameter is wrong. what should it be?

Comment: the depth is an enumeration, try `Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`

Comment: the final line would look like `Image buffer = new Bitmap(200,200,Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);`

Answer (score 1):

People say use `DoubleBufferred = true;`, but you can easily change the `DoubleBufferred` parameter on the form to `true`, without needing to  use code.

Comment: And how can you change it without using code?