# Blinking Form when background Image set to it c#

Tags: c#, winforms

When I fix a Background to my winform, It is getting blink on form load. I have a table layout panel on my form and I kept all my controls on the table layout panel.

I set the backcolor of tablelayout panel to Transparent and Set the Image to the background. Why am I getting blink on my form load?

Comment: Have you enabled DoubleBuffering?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298148/how-to-avoid-blinking-in-form-invalidate

Answer (score 0):

WinForms doesn't handle transparency very well (As I'm sure you may have noticed, not all WinForms controls even support it). The blink is caused because as your TableLayoutPanel is loaded, as well as all its items, the Form has to find the correct 'image' (Because the control doesn't support transparency in the same way as WPF or a game does, it instead uses an image of the controls behind it) to display. It must go through this process as each of your controls are loaded, hence the blinking. You can try enabling DoubleBuffering on your Form, however, if I recall correctly, this can cause issues with transparency.

If you find that you are using a lot of transparency and/or want to customise your Form a lot more, I suggest you take a look at WPF. It offers far greater control over your Form (Window in WPF) as well as supporting transparency on every single control.